# react js filter through an array of objects and compare values within to get the closest value to a variable

Tags: reactjs

I would like to filter through the gamesList array get the creatorRating values
then compare them to get the creatorRating closest to the currentUserRating

```
const gamesList [
{"gameId":"randomId1","creatorRating: 555},
{"gameId":"randomId2","creatorRating: 666},
{"gameId":"randomId3","creatorRating: 777},
]
```

so basically this is what I would like to achieve

gamesList.foreach

get creatorRating

compare creatorRating with currentUserRating

get Closest

which gets me

closestRating = {"gameId":"randomId1","creatorRating: 555}

then

joinGame(gameId) // is randomId1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initilize two variables index and difference
check if we have exact the same rating so we break the loop , else for each iteration we check the dif

```js
  const rat = 900;
  const gamesList = [
    { gameId: "randomId1", creatorRating: 555 },
    { gameId: "randomId2", creatorRating: 666 },
    { gameId: "randomId3", creatorRating: 777 }
  ];
  const getElement = () => {
    let indexElement = 0;
    let differences = Math.abs(gamesList[0].creatorRating - rat);

    for (const el of gamesList) {
      if (el.creatorRating === rat) {
        indexElement = gamesList.indexOf(el);
        break;
      } else {
        const newDiff = Math.abs(el.creatorRating - rat);
        if (newDiff < differences) {
          differences = newDiff;
          indexElement = gamesList.indexOf(el);
        }
      }
    }
    return indexElement;
  };
```

ference.

Comment: you're welcome just you need to add break; to stop looping in the block if(el.creatorRating === rat)